# Changing the file_field_tag textfield size for chrome & firefox

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

HI guys,

I'm having a problem trying to change the default textfield of file_field_tag on chrome and FF, it works fine on IE but on the other browsers it is not applying the size.

My code is.

> file_field_tag "#{ compliance.id }_document" , :size => '2

Dont know if i might be doing something wrong but i am sure its a very small thing that i have missed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your sure this size works in HTML with this one? It's maybe not a rails issue. But HTML compatibility :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML 4.01 specification says that this attribute, in case of `<input type="file">`, defines the width in pixels, not in characters.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

Besides that, you should use a CSS for width definition. You have two options: use an inline style:

```
file_field_tag "#{compliance.id}_document", :style="width: 2em"
```

or (preferable) add a class to the tag, and the CSS definitions place in your stylesheet:

```
file_field_tag "#{compliance.id}_document", :class="short"

/* CSS */
input.short {
  width: 2em;
}
/* ..or if you expect some intelligent browsers, you may be more specific: */
input[type='file'].short {
  width: 2em;
}
```

You may need to experiment a little, since file controls may refuse to accept your width. The default stylesheet rules of every browser may define some other rules, stronger than your ones.

For Firefox you may see the definitions in a file `forms.css`. On my system the location is `/usr/lib64/xulrunner-1.9.2/res/forms.css`.

There is a definition, which may help you:

```
input[type="file"] > input[type="text"] {
  ....
```

Define a width for `input[type="file"].short > input[type="text"]` and you should be OK. Note however, that this rule may be changed in every version of the browser.

Comment: Thanks Arsen, the inline style worked just fine than actually trying to specify the size of the field in ruby.. i used :style => "width" instead.